# Does Mono.block() or Flux.block() block the thread (and keep it waiting) or only block execution flow and release the thread in reactive spring?

Tags: project-reactor

I have a restful api microservice, that calls another remote rest api and respond back to the clients. The remote api takes time for each requests and the threads are blocked until the response is received in traditional resttemplate. I want to improve the performance by using the reactor. Does Mono.block() or Flux.block() block the thread (and keep it waiting) or only block execution flow and release the thread in reactive spring?

Comment: It blocks the (subscribing) thread.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use Webflux, so you can use both reactive WebClient (for remote API call) and controllers (for your restfull api microservice), so you can avoid using *block()* at all. If you cannot, but your current technology offers an async API, you can create bindings using sinks (Ex: [exposing data received through listener api as a Flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_asynchronous_but_single_threaded_push)).